# Managing bundles in inventory

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm thinking of switching to the Shopify platform, and I had a question regarding product bundles. Currently, customers are able to purchase bundled items on my website that are items composed of other items within the assortment. For example, customers can buy a bundle item that's a monitor, keyboard and CPU as one set. Within the product catalog the bundle is it's own individual SKU. However, customers can also buy just the monitor as a separate item. In each scenario the monitor has it's own SKU as well as the bundle. However, when a customer purchases this item instead of reducing the inventory by one bundle, we actually reduce the inventory by each of the SKUs in the bundle. So if a customer purchases a bundle, the stock of the monitor, CPU and keyboard are each reduced by one. Essentially, the bundle is acting as a ghost item online and in the backend we're actually just working with the individual SKU's that compose that item.

I've seen multiple bundeling apps on Shopify, but none that address this need. Does anybody know of an app that would support this functionality? Or is there native functionality within the shopify platform that would support this?

Answer (score 1):

I built an App many years ago that does exactly this. You create a product with infinite inventory composed of X other products, give it a price, and sell it as a bundle. When the order is booked, the App updates the individual product inventory levels, and all is well.

The main problem no one has ever solved with this (short of using an expensive Enterprise inventory management approach) is that it is not possible to not have the occasional oversell on inventory. Shopify only checks inventory for managed products, and bundles have no management. So if you are not concerned with inventory management at the point a customer moves from cart to checkout, this kind of App is good enough for you. Otherwise, you need to spend $$$ on Enterprise level code.

Comment: Is it an app in the Spotify ecosystem? One more question, what do you mean by managed products?

Comment: It's an App I provide for clients, not in App store as I do not want to support it there. Shopify has inventory management you can turn on/off. That is what I mean. You decide if they "check" inventory levels or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know of an app that would support this functionality?

I believe there are quite a few apps that support this now. Our App supports it via the 'Synchronize Inventory' task: [Products Assistant](https://apps.shopify.com/shopify-assistant)